# .Net 7 iOS app crashes on launch 'Got a SIGABRT while executing native code'

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, maui

I'm migrating my Xamarin.iOS app to .Net-7, and the app crashes on launch with the following log:

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1d8e3101c):0x1d8e3100c  ff 0f 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6 10 29 80 d2 01 10 00 d4  .._..._..)......
0x1d8e3101c  03 01 00 54 7f 23 03 d5 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91  ...T.#...{......
0x1d8e3102c  e8 dd ff 97 bf 03 00 91 fd 7b c1 a8 ff 0f 5f d6  .........{...._.
0x1d8e3103c  c0 03 5f d6 7f 23 03 d5 ff c3 00 d1 f4 4f 01 a9  .._..#.......O..

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at System.Environment:FailFast <0x00028>
      at System.Environment:FailFast <0x00018>
      at System.SR:InternalGetResourceString <0x001ba>
      at System.SR:GetResourceString <0x00044>
      at System.SR:get_Arg_DllNotFoundException <0x00010>
      at System.DllNotFoundException:.ctor <0x00010>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_direct_void__this__ <0x00080>
      at <unknown> <0x00000>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at Sys:<GetEnv>g____PInvoke|0_0 <0x0004a>
      at Sys:GetEnv <0x0009c>
      at System.Environment:GetEnvironmentVariableCore <0x00028>
      at System.Environment:GetEnvironmentVariable <0x00026>
      at System.AppContextConfigHelper:GetBooleanConfig <0x00032>
      at Settings:.cctor <0x00046>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_direct_void <0x0007a>
      at <unknown> <0x00000>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode:get_Invariant <0x0000a>
      at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler:GetNeutralResourcesLanguage <0x00036>
      at System.Resources.ResourceManager:CommonAssemblyInit <0x000b2>
      at System.Resources.ResourceManager:.ctor <0x000ce>
      at System.SR:get_ResourceManager <0x00028>
      at System.SR:InternalGetResourceString <0x002ae>
      at System.SR:GetResourceString <0x00044>
      at System.SR:get_Arg_DllNotFoundException <0x00010>
      at System.DllNotFoundException:.ctor <0x00010>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_direct_void__this__ <0x00080>
      at <unknown> <0x00000>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at Sys:Malloc <0x0004a>
      at System.Runtime.InteropServices.NativeMemory:Alloc <0x00040>
      at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal:AllocHGlobal <0x00010>
      at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal:AllocHGlobal <0x00016>
      at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal:StringToHGlobalUTF8 <0x00074>
      at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal:StringToHGlobalAuto <0x00010>
      at ObjCRuntime.TransientString:.ctor <0x0003c>
      at ObjCRuntime.Class:objc_getClass <0x00020>
      at ObjCRuntime.Class:GetHandle <0x00010>
      at Foundation.NSObject:.cctor <0x00030>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_direct_void <0x0007a>
      at <unknown> <0x00000>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at ObjCRuntime.Runtime:Initialize <0x0016e>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_Runtime/InitializationOptions* <0x00086>
      at <unknown> <0x00000>
=================================================================
```

.Csproj:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net7.0-ios</TargetFramework>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
      <ImplicitUsings>false</ImplicitUsings>
      <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
      <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
      <RuntimeIdentifiers>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
      <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
      <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Project>
```

I'm using Xcode 15 & Visual studio for mac 17.6.5 (latest available)
I tried to downgrade Xcode to 14.3, same result
I created new iOS app from scratch, the results are the same. Always crash on launch

Comment: 1. Please try to Delete bin and obj and rebuild the project.  2. Please help provide a binlog of a working build (right after clean), and another binlog of a build that crashes, see:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki/Diagnosis#binary-build-logs

Comment: Actually remove bin & obj for all folders in the solution and remove .nuget packages folder worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Good to see it works, I posted it as an answer, you can accept it as answer as it will be helpful for those people who are facing the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a
> fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

For those who build the MAUI iOS crashes and encounter the error log above, especially when migrating from Xamarin iOS app to MAUI iOS(.NET 7) can try doing steps below to fix it.

1. Delete bin and obj folders in the solution.
2. Remove the .nuget packages folder.

Windows: `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`

Mac/Linux: `~/.nuget/packages`