# Getting "Got a SIGABRT while executing native code." when tapping an entry in MAUI

Tags: c#, ios, .net, maui, maui-ios

This happens with every project.

I am using dotnet sdk version 8.0.

Also, I have installed the workloads for maui

```
Installed Workload Id      Manifest Version       Installation Source
---------------------------------------------------------------------
ios                        17.2.8043/8.0.100      SDK 8.0.200        
maui                       8.0.7/8.0.100          SDK 8.0.200        
android                    34.0.85/8.0.100        SDK 8.0.200
```

Created a new Maui Project and added an entry on it, but as soon as I tap it the app crashes and this is displayed in the logs

```
com.companyname.mauitemp: 9952
2024-03-15 13:04:57.782043+0100 MauiTemp[9952:123265] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "fetch" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2024-03-15 13:04:58.081837+0100 MauiTemp[9952:123645] dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's has hidden visibility or is defined in more than one translation unit. They should all have public visibility. N3icu6number4impl20AffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE.
2024-03-15 13:04:58.082140+0100 MauiTemp[9952:123645] dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's has hidden visibility or is defined in more than one translation unit. They should all have public visibility. N3icu6number4impl20AffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE.
2024-03-15 13:04:58.082540+0100 MauiTemp[9952:123645] dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's has hidden visibility or is defined in more than one translation unit. They should all have public visibility. N3icu6number4impl20AffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE.
2024-03-15 13:04:58.082667+0100 MauiTemp[9952:123645] dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's has hidden visibility or is defined in more than one translation unit. They should all have public visibility. N3icu6number4impl20AffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE.
2024-03-15 13:04:58.083041+0100 MauiTemp[9952:123645] dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's has hidden visibility or is defined in more than one translation unit. They should all have public visibility. N3icu6number4impl20AffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE.
2024-03-15 13:04:58.091444+0100 MauiTemp[9952:123645] dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's has hidden visibility or is defined in more than one translation unit. They should all have public visibility. N3icu6number4impl20AffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE.
2024-03-15 13:04:58.092416+0100 MauiTemp[9952:123645] dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's has hidden visibility or is defined in more than one translation unit. They should all have public visibility. N3icu6number4impl20AffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE.
2024-03-15 13:04:58.094306+0100 MauiTemp[9952:123645] dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's has hidden visibility or is defined in more than one translation unit. They should all have public visibility. N3icu6number4impl20AffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE.
2024-03-15 13:04:58.095175+0100 MauiTemp[9952:123645] dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's has hidden visibility or is defined in more than one translation unit. They should all have public visibility. N3icu6number4impl20AffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE, N3icu6number4impl30PropertiesAffixPatternProviderE.
2024-03-15 13:04:58.590383+0100 MauiTemp[9952:123265] [TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has been added to a window. Table view: <_UIMoreListTableView: 0x104c1f200; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000c78a80>; backgroundColor = <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x60000175b880; name = tableBackgroundColor>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000783c20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <UIMoreListController: 0x10413f880>>

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x1022b40a0 - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x10226428c - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x102586bc8 - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : sigabrt_signal_handler.cold.1
    0x1022b3960 - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_setup_stat_profiler
    0x100c1fc60 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x1016ef1d0 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : pthread_kill
    0x1801655c0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib : abort
    0x1801e378c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib : malloc_vreport
    0x1801e3950 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib : malloc_report
    0x1801d78a0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib : find_zone_and_free
    0x181dd5fb0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : _ZN3icu6Locale10setToBogusEv
    0x181dd7954 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : _ZN3icu6LocaleaSERKS0_
    0x181f455f4 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : _ZN3icu6number24LocalizedNumberFormatterC2EONS0_4impl10MacroPropsERKNS_6LocaleE
    0x181ef1494 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : _ZN3icu13DecimalFormat5touchER10UErrorCode
    0x181dda37c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : _ZN3icu13DecimalFormatC1ERKNS_13UnicodeStringEPNS_20DecimalFormatSymbolsER11UParseErrorR10UErrorCode
    0x181dd73ec - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : unum_open
    0x1804a0bf0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __cficu_unum_open
    0x1803e15cc - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFNumberFormatterCreate
    0x180da4f8c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation : -[NSNumberFormatter _regenerateFormatter]
    0x180da6040 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation : -[NSNumberFormatter stringForObjectValue:]
    0x18504ab10 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIKeyboardGetNumbersStringForActiveInputMode
    0x1850a1f70 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIKBMoreKeyStringForActiveInputMode
    0x1850fe1ac - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar updateLocalizedKeysOnKeyplane:]
    0x1850ff540 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar updateLocalizedKeysForKeyplane:updateAllKeyplanes:]
    0x185104588 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar setKeyplaneName:]
    0x18510a714 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar setToInitialKeyplane]
    0x18510a5f4 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar showKeyboardWithInputMode:renderConfig:inputTraits:screenTraits:splitTraits:reload:]
    0x1851e7bcc - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardImpl finishLayoutChangeWithArguments:]
    0x1851e826c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardImpl updateLayout]
    0x1851db674 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardImpl _setupDelegate:delegateSame:hardwareKeyboardStateChanged:endingInputSessionIdentifier:force:delayEndInputSession:]
    0x1851d95cc - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:delayEndInputSession:]
    0x184e06f84 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate _reloadInputViewsForKeyWindowSceneResponder:force:fromBecomeFirstResponder:]
    0x184e06190 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate _reloadInputViewsForResponder:force:fromBecomeFirstResponder:]
    0x185417cec - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) _reloadInputViewsFromFirstResponder:]
    0x1854129fc - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
    0x1858f81c0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder]
    0x18570c4a0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder]
    0x1856d097c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessaryActivatingSelection:]
    0x1856acf08 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UITextSelectionInteraction _checkForRepeatedTap:gestureLocationOut:]
    0x1856adc9c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UITextSelectionInteraction _handleMultiTapGesture:]
    0x1853ecf04 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
    0x184e6a168 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UITextMultiTapRecognizer onStateUpdate:]
    0x184f2b560 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:]
    0x184f32f60 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions
    0x184f307e8 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions
    0x184f2ff44 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureForActiveEvents]
    0x184f22bd0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate
    0x184f21ecc - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:]
    0x184f21c3c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:]
    0x185421df8 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
    0x1854017c8 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
    0x1854849d8 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
    0x185487824 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __processEventQueue
    0x185480218 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __eventFetcherSourceCallback
    0x18040ee88 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
    0x18040edd0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSource0
    0x18040e540 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSources0
    0x180408c28 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopRun
    0x180408514 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    0x18ef06ae4 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
    0x1853e8040 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication _run]
    0x1853ebcc8 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIApplicationMain
    0x101b93f44 - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib : xamarin_UIApplicationMain
    0x1022c4950 - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : do_icall
    0x1022c31f0 - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : do_icall_wrapper
    0x1022b7c3c - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_interp_exec_method
    0x1022b5810 - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x1021cea74 - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x1023899ac - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x102390f8c - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked
    0x102222d3c - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_jit_exec
    0x101bd7b00 - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib : xamarin_main
    0x10026ab44 - /Users/bekimpeci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5CA6B45-82F8-4974-98EA-F8DCE03B6AF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C09B57-F811-4AF9-9A48-C26182582703/MauiTemp.app/MauiTemp : main
    0x100cfd544 - Unknown
    0x1006920e0 - Unknown
    0xd446000000000000 - Unknown

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1017a49ec):0x1017a49dc  c0 03 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6 10 29 80 d2 01 10 00 d4  .._..._..)......
0x1017a49ec  e3 00 00 54 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91 ce e2 ff 97  ...T.{..........
0x1017a49fc  bf 03 00 91 fd 7b c1 a8 c0 03 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6  .....{...._..._.
0x1017a4a0c  70 0a 80 d2 01 10 00 d4 e3 00 00 54 fd 7b bf a9  p..........T.{..

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:xamarin_UIApplicationMain <0x000b8>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x0006e>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x0015a>
      at MauiTemp.Program:Main <0x0002c>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x0007e>
      at <unknown> <0x00000>
=================================================================
```

First I tried the solution from this problem: [.Net 7 iOS app crashes on launch 'Got a SIGABRT while executing native code'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77347242/net-7-ios-app-crashes-on-launch-got-a-sigabrt-while-executing-native-code)
I tried running it on different simulators but no luck.
This happens in every project, even in empty ones

Answer (score 0):

So, based on this post on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnetMAUI/comments/1bd1cwz/selecting_a_linkbutton_in_a_webview_maui_app_for/

MAUI has problems with iOS version 17, so going with version 16 and works perfectly

Comment: I doubt you can ask people to downgrade iOS. Besides, that reddit post is about a webview control, your description of the problem does not include anything about webview.